# How to save a png file into database, FLASK?

Tags: python, selenium, flask, phantomjs

I have a small problem, i want to upload a (screenshot) image that have been taken by `selenium driver` and `PhantomJS` to my website and to put it into the database .

I'am using the `get_screenshot_as_file()` function to save the image in the current directory, this function just gives me `True` or `False` value if the process successfully done, but what i need is the file name so i can save it in the database.

Here are my views and models snippets:

**models.py**

```
class Driver(PhantomJS):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Driver, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._log = StderrLog()

class ScreenShot(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    image = db.Column(db.String(255), default=None)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80))
    describe = db.Column(db.Text)

    def __init__(self, image, title, describe):
        self.image = image
        self.title = title
        self.describe = describe

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Title %r" %self.title
```

**views.py**

```
from blog.form import ScreenShotForm
from blog.models import ScreenShot, StderrLog, Driver

@app.route('/my_works/', methods=('GET','POST'))
@only_author
def my_works():
    blog = Blog.query.first()
    form = ScreenShotForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        url = request.args.get(url_for('index'), form.title.data)
        width = int(request.args.get("w", 1200))
        min_height = int(request.args.get("h", 400))
        wait_time = float(request.args.get("t", 20)) / 1000  # ms

        driver = Driver()
        driver.set_window_position(0, 0)
        driver.set_window_size(width, min_height)

        driver.set_page_load_timeout(100)
        driver.implicitly_wait(100)
        driver.get(url)

        driver.set_window_size(width, min_height)
        time.sleep(wait_time)

        sys.stderr.write(driver.execute_script("return document.readyState") + "\n")

        image = driver.get_screenshot_as_file(os.urandom(3).encode('hex')+'.png')

        title = form.title.data
        describe = form.describe.data

        scrshot = ScreenShot(image, title, describe)
        db.session.add(scrshot)
        db.session.commit()
        driver.quit()
        flash('Screenshot added.')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
        #driver.get_screenshot_as_file('foo.png')
        #return "<h1>Image saved</h1>"
        #return Response(png, mimetype="image/png")
    return render_template('blog/my_works.html', blog=blog, form=form)
```

**form.py**

```
class ScreenShotForm(Form):
    title = StringField('Site',[validators.Required(), validators.length(max=80)])
    describe = TextAreaField('Describtion', validators=[validators.Required()])
```

As you can see, am using `os.urandom(3).encode('hex')+'.png'` so it can gives me a random names for my screenshots so i can't get confused, in the database i get 1 which means `True`, also inside my project folder i got the screenshot `25de0a.png` file perfectly , sounds great !!!!, but i don't want that to happen, i want to get the file name rather than `True` or `False` expressions.

Here a snippet of what i got in the database:

```
+----+-------+-------------------------+-------------------+
| id | image | title                   | describe          |
+----+-------+-------------------------+-------------------+
|  6 | 0     | http://www.youtube.com/ | testing testing . |
|  7 | 1     | http://www.youtube.com/ | asdasfasfwf324214 |
+----+-------+-------------------------+-------------------+
```

i tried the `get_screenshot_as_png()` function, and what i got is the source code of the image.

It would be nice if the results were as follows:

```
+----+-------+-------------------------+-------------------+
| id | image | title                   | describe          |
+----+-------+-------------------------+-------------------+
|  6 | 25de0a.png     | http://www.youtube.com/ | testing testing . |
|  7 | 25de0a.png     | http://www.youtube.com/ | asdasfasfwf324214 |
+----+-------+-------------------------+-------------------+
```

Eventually, please any help would be tons tons tons appreciated :) .

Comment: any body guys :( !!!

Comment: Have you considered uploading the file yourself? http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/fileuploads/

Comment: Thanks man for your interest ;) , @pjcunningham answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass the wanted filename into the `get_screenshot_as_file` method (as you are doing now). The `get_screenshot_as_file` method returns True if the file was successfully written, otherwise False.

Your code should be something like :

```
image_filename = os.urandom(3).encode('hex')+'.png' 

if driver.get_screenshot_as_file(image_filename):
    # file was successfully written
    title = form.title.data
    describe = form.describe.data

    scrshot = ScreenShot(image_filename, title, describe)
    db.session.add(scrshot)
    db.session.commit()
else:
    # file was not written
    pass
```